# That sequence is convergent pointwise but not uniformly convergent, but for what $\varepsilon$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm trying for too long time solve this but without success. I'm tired and need help.

> Show that sequence of funcions converges pointwise but not uniformly convergent: $$ f_n(x)=\frac{n^2x}{1+n^3x^2} $$
>   Where $f_n(x): [0,1] \rightarrow R$

**MY ATTEMPT**

First I whot that conerges pointwise:

if $x\neq 0$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\frac{n^2x}{1+n^3x^2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\frac{2nx}{3n^2x^2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\frac{2x}{6nx^2}}=0
$$

if $x = 0$ $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\frac{n^2x}{1+n^3x^2}}=0$$
So $f_n \rightarrow 0$.

Now i wanna show that convergence is not uniformly:

$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f_n(x)-0|=|f_n(x)|=f_n(x)=\frac{n^2x}{1+n^3x^2}>\frac{x}{1+n^3x^2}
$$
...

I don't know continue this!

Comment: What is $f_n\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$?

Comment: $f_n(1/n^2)=\frac{1}{1+n}$ but what this help me? I can choose one $x$ that depends of $n$?

Comment: You miscalculated. The denominator is $1+n^3 x^2$. If the sequence were uniformly convergent, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, you could choose an $N$ independent of $x$ such that $\lvert f_n - f\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $n\geqslant N$. Showing that each $f_n$ attains a value $\geqslant \frac12$ in a point $x_n$ shows that you cannot choose $N$ independent of $x$, since it would have to work for all $x$, including $x_n$.

Comment: $$f_n(1/n^2)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$ is the correct anwser for your first question.

Comment: I'll need to mature a little better these ideas. Made much sense. I am very grateful.

Comment: We can look at this result as, in other words, that if we have a subsequence of a sequence that is not uniformly convergent so the sequence is also not.
In this case we take the sequence $f_{n_k}(k)$ where $k=\frac{1}{k^2}$.


This ideas are true?

We can write better this ideas above?

Comment: We don't need to consider a subsequence here. That a sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on a set $X$ means $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \left\lbrace \lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert : x \in X\right\rbrace = 0.$$ Here we have $$\sup \left\lbrace \lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert : x \in [0,1]\right\rbrace \geqslant \left\lvert f_n\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right\rvert = \frac{1}{1+\frac1n} \geqslant \frac12.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach from the comments above is to find the maximum value of the function $f_n(x)$ by setting its derivative to zero.  I find that the maximum occurs where $x=n^{-3/2}$ and the maximum value is $\sqrt{n}/2$.  So even as the function goes pointwise to zero the maximum value goes to infinity -- therefore there's no way to find $\epsilon$ that traps $f(x)$ within $\epsilon$ of zero for $x\in [0,1]$.